# Maintain negative contentOffset in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am dynamically adding UIButtons of varying sizes to a horizontal scroll view. Since these buttons are in an RTL language, I want them to be right aligned and I should be able to scroll to the left to see the reset of the content. To achieve this I set `contentOffset.x` of the scrollview to a negative value. This works fine at the start, but as soon as I start scrolling and release, the offset goes back to 0 and now everything is left aligned. How can  I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `bounces` property of your scrollView to NO:

```
scrollview.bounces = NO;
```

That will prevent your scrollview to bounce back to its edge automatically.

From the docs:

> if YES, bounces past edge of content and back again

Comment: This does not work (anymore at least). With the option off, the offset is reset to 0 as soon as you start scrolling.